# ASP.NET AJAX Can not find the controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, routes

For the last 3 hours I've been trying to make this work:
Here is a picture of my project:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/961ZW.png

This is my HomeController.cs in the Controllers folder:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static int OnSubmit()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the AJAX script from my Index.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'HomeController/OnSubmit',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
</script>
```

Every time I try to run the script, it shows
"POST http://localhost:62738/HomeController/OnSubmit 404 (Not Found)" in the console.
I've been trying different urls, @URL.Action, creating another class and placing it in different folders to see if it even works, but nothing. Always the same error. Also tried to place [HttpPost] under the [WebMethod]

Comment: I think you need to replace(not under)  [WebMethod] to  [HttpPost]. Also remove the static keyword. MVC doesn't allow static in Action method

Comment: It worked.. Thanks! I think that the problem was from the static keyword. Tried replacing WebMethod with HttpPost before.

Comment: Glad that helped. please accept the Answer that i have posted, which will helps to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with replace(not under) `[WebMethod]` to `[HttpPost]` and remove the `static` keyword. MVC doesn't allow `static` in Action method.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public int OnSubmit()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```